# Merge rows when value doesn't change in continuous time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I need to summarize a table that has this information: Serial Number, StartDate, EndDate, StatusID and TimeInState, what I need is to merge rows that keep the same StatusId during a continuous time (EndDate of row is same as StartDate of the other), for example, for this case:

[image: Dataset]

I need to output this:

[image: Desired Output Table]

I cant come with a solution yet since I think I can't use `Group By`, I need to merge rows with specific SerialNumber when the StatusId doesn't change in a continuous time.

Comment: We much prefer data as formatted text than images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical gaps and islands problem, where you want to group together adjacent rows that have the same serial number and status.

Here is a standard approach, that uses the difference between `row_number`s to identify the groups:

```
select
    serialNumber,
    min(beginDateTime) beginDateTime,
    max(endDateTime) endDateTime,
    statusId,
    sum(timeInStateInMilliseconds) timeInStateInMilliseconds
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by serialNumber order by beginDateTime) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by serialNumber , statusId order by beginDateTime) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by serialNumber, statusId, rn1 - rn2
```

Comment: Thank you @DaleK , I did upvote, but since I am new user (less than 15 reputation) it seems is does not show to public

Comment: Thats fine - just keep at it and soon you'll have the rep.